# Is it an option to put an indefinite article before a professional name?

Tags: articles, determiners

Thanks for checking your forecast out inside WESH.com. I’m **(a) meteorologist** Eric Burris.

-- [WESH.com/weather](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/446)

I’ve read that predicative complement “*can have the form of an AdjP or of a bare role NP (a count singular with no determiner, such as President of the Republic, treasurer, etc.)* - CGEL,p.253”. Is it an option to put an indefinite article in front of *meteorologist*? (I don’t decide whether he pronounces ‘a’.)

Comment: I heard it as: *Let’s check **the** forecast out inside WESH dot com. I’m **meteorologist** Eric Burris*. No article **a**. However, without your transcription, I'm sure I can't decipher Eric Burris's name correctly. Listening to it once again, there seems to be some syllable between *check* and *the* indeed, but *check in* or *checking* or *checkin'* would sound strange.

Comment: @DamkerngT. For I'm a poor listener, I've changed OP. And even now I can't present my confident one, neither comment on yours.

Comment: Putting the first few words aside (which I'm still in doubt too, for my listening is also not 100%), I am quite sure that there is no *a* before *meteorologist* in this speech. As for English usage in general, I believe that there should not be an indefinite article before job title or occupation before someone's name. I think of it as an adjective before a proper name. And since we don't say *I'm a Eric Burris* (except for a very rare occasion), I think we don't normally say *I'm a meteorologist Eric Burris,* too.

Comment: I'm an AmE speaker. He is definitely saying, "I'm meteorologist Eric Burr(is? sh?)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think yours is very persuasive.

Comment: It's "*Thanks for checking* the forecast out inside WESH.com, I'm meteorologist [Eric Burris](http://www.wesh.com/tv/news-team/Meteorologist/-/11789914/17794738/-/ov6nk5z/-/index.html)" - no article

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, use of the indefinite article with a professional title is generally incorrect in standard English. More particularly, it is incorrect when using it *as a title*:

> **Incorrect:** He is a CIO Smith.
>
> **Incorrect:** I am an exterminator Jones.

There is one exception: If the speaker intends humourous effect, this construction can be used. It basically says "*Yup, that's me, that's what I am. Hahaha*." However, it is non-standard.

It is correct to use the indefinite article when the title is used as an occupation:

> **Correct:** I am a CIO, and my name is Smith.
>
> **Correct:** He's an exterminator. His name is Jones.

Other than occupational or humourous usage, do not use an article:

> **Correct:** He is President Smith.
>
> **Correct:** I'm meteorologist Eric Burris.

At its simplest, a title works like this:

*Is it being used as a title? Don't use an article.*

*Is it being used to describe an occupation? Use an article.*